# add entries to JSON in a while loop

Tags: javascript, json

How to add key value pair into an JSON object in a while loop?

```
var sName = "string_";
var aKeys = ["1", "2", "3"];
var sKey = "key";
var n = 1;
 var aObj = {};

var l = aKeys.length;
for(let i=0; i < l; i++){
   while(n < 5)
  {
    n += 1;
    aObj.sKey = sName.concat(n);
  }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(aObj));
```

expected output:

```
{"sKey":"string_2", "sKey":"string_3", "sKey":"string_4"}
```

Comment: expected output: {"sKey":"string_2", "sKey":"string_3", "sKey":"string_4"}

Comment: You can't have keys with duplicate names.

Comment: this is not possible to have the same key for every value. and btw, you are overwriting `String`.

Comment: You can't have same key more than once in a single object.

Comment: Hi Dali. Welcome to SO. Your expected output is not a valid JSON, each key in a JSON object needs to be unique. If you want a key to hold multiple values, then it is preferable that it be an array e.g.
`{"sKey": ["string_2", "string_3", "string_4"]}`

Comment: thanx, my real key will be a iterated one, and my value will be a Set. I just wanted to simplify example. How do I add the entry pair to a JSON without incremented [i] like in a for loop?

Comment: You're saying that the value will be a Set. What will be the key?

Comment: in my real script it will be a new Set() , and the keys will be new Strings, or if equals will not be added as new key.

Comment: If you're not actually expecting there to be duplicate keys then you need to show the correct output that you are expecting instead of the invalid one you listed.

Comment: sorry about not being accurate. When i use a new Map() and set the entries I get the right result. But how to with a JSON?

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned, `Object` can't have duplicate keys.
Try:

```js
var value = "string_";
var sKey = "sKey_"
var i = 1;
var Obj = {};

while(i < 5)
{
  Obj[sKey.concat(i)] = value.concat(i++);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(Obj));
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand the comment.

Comment: That is a Snippet from my real Script. Just to see that the keys are new (not the same) they will be from our API methods

Comment: OUTPUT: {"sKey_1":"string_2", "sKey_2":"string_3", "sKey_3":"string_4"}

Comment: `String` is a built in object. Don't overwrite it by assigning to it.